# Days in a month by month number

Tags: java

I've been trying to solve this problem in practice and for some reason it won't work. it's supposed to be a method that would take an int(month) and return the number of days in it.. for example, daysInMonth(3) = 31 because there are 31 days in March.
this is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    daysInMonth();
}

public static void daysInMonth (int month){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to number of days in a month\nChoose a month ( Jan - 1, Feb -2,...): ");
    int month = input.nextInt();
    if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) {
        System.out.println("30 days");
    } else if ( month == 2){
        System.out.println("28 days");
    } else {
        System.out.println("31 days");
    }   
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are encountering?

Comment: Your daysInMonth metod is expecting a parameter but you call it without one in your main method.

Comment: sometimes February has more than 28 days

Comment: Your  compiler gives you an error and the error message should be easy to understand. Try to spend a little more time researching and trying to solve your issue before giving up and posting a question.

Answer (score 1):

A parameter is not neccesary - you are asking for an input in the method.
Declare your method like this:

```
public static void daysInMonth ()
```

Or remove the input completely and enter a parameter when calling the method.
Like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    daysInMonth(3);
}

public static void daysInMonth (int month){
    if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) {
        System.out.println("30 days");
    } else if ( month == 2){
        System.out.println("28 days");
    } else {
        System.out.println("31 days");
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `java.time.*` classes are more efficient. Built into Java 8 and later.

Use like this ;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to number of days in a month\nChoose a month ( Jan - 1, Feb - 2,...): ");
    int month = input.nextInt();
    daysInMonth(month);
}

public static void daysInMonth(int month) {
    YearMonth yearMonthObject = YearMonth.of(LocalDateTime.now().getYear(), month);
    System.out.println(yearMonthObject.lengthOfMonth() + " days");
}
```